# Updating jLabel based on jSpinner

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

Right now I have a jFrame Spinner that just has numbers. I am storing the value of the spinner like this

```
    int value = (Integer) jSpinner1.getValue();
```

And am then outputting it to a jLabel like this

```
    jLabel5.setText("Counter = " + value );
```

I was wondering if there is a way to update the jLabel every time the number is changed on the spinner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Add a ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html#addChangeListener-javax.swing.event.ChangeListener-) and set your label there.

```
JLabel l = ...;
JSpinner spinner = ...;
spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
  public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    l.setText("Counter = " + spinner.getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. When you have a sec can you click the check to accept my solution?

Comment: My bad, Check is clicked!